# Webistrano - Phusion Passenger - Could not find rake

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, webistrano

I'm having issues running deploy tasks in Webistrano.
This only when I run Webistrano from Nginx with Phusion Passenger.

When I run Webistano with the following command, everything runs fine.

> ruby script/server -d -p 3000 -e production

But when running it from from Phusion Passenger (compiled with "passenger-install-nginx-module") and I want to do a deploy (the application is running) I get the following error in my log:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `materialize': Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:172:in `specs_for'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:161:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
```

My bundle gemlist:

```
  Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (2.3.11)
  * actionpack (2.3.11)
  * activerecord (2.3.11)
  * activeresource (2.3.11)
  * activesupport (2.3.11)
  * bundler (1.1.5)
  * capistrano (2.6.0)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * exception_notification (2.3.3.0)
  * highline (1.6.13)
  * mocha (0.9.8)
  * mysql (2.8.1)
  * net-scp (1.0.4)
  * net-sftp (2.0.5)
  * net-ssh (2.5.2)
  * net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
  * open4 (0.9.3)
  * rack (1.1.3)
  * rails (2.3.11)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * syntax (1.0.0)
```

This is in my nginx.conf :

```
passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.15;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
```

And my specific server config:

```
passenger_enabled on;
rails_env production;
```

It's strange that running this with WeBrick just works as it should, but passenger via nginx isn't.
I'm not very into Ruby, and I don't really know where I should start looking.

I install ruby from the source, no rvm.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The error comes from this line :

> ruby script/runner -e production ' deployment = Deployment.find(1085); Webistrano::Deployer.new(deployment).invoke_task! '

Works as aspected when executed from commandline, but doesn't when executed from within the app via nginx/passenger.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but I'd guess that the error is related to the user that it's being run under.  Passenger runs under the Apache user.  There is an issue with git that is discussed on the Webistrano wiki that is similar.

https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/wiki/Installing-with-Phusion-Passenger